# Problemas al leer la fecha en html

Tags: javascript, html, date, google-apps-script

Estoy creando un script en google donde se insertan datos en un formulario  y luego insertados me retorna una tabla con los datos que he insertado así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema esta en que tengo que poner la fecha de esa forma para que me lea los datos, porque si quiero leer la fecha que inserte antes por ejemplo como "24 05 2022" o uso datetime-local me sale un error en mi consola al mostrar mis contactos que es este (en insertarlos no tengo problema, solo me ocurre el error cuando quiero leer esos datos):

> ```
> userCodeAppPanel:78 Uncaught TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
>     at Function.from (<anonymous>)
>     at crearTablaContactosCorrectamente (userCodeAppPanel:78:19)......
> ```

Este es el código con el que leo los datos:

```javascript
function crearTablaContactosCorrectamente(obj) {   
//crea tablas de distintos tipos y agrega los datos

    tabla = document.createElement("table");
    tabla.id = "tablaContactos";
    let tablaHeader = document.createElement("thead");
    let tablaBody = document.createElement("tbody");

    let primeraFila = document.createElement("tr");
    for(let i=0; i<obj[0].length; i++) {
        let celda = document.createElement("td");
        celda.textContent = obj[0][i];
        primeraFila.appendChild(celda);
    }

    //agregar la fila al header de la tabla
    tablaHeader.appendChild(primeraFila);
    tabla.appendChild(tablaHeader);
    //primeraFila.appendChild(celdaOpciones);

    //body de la tabla
    for(let i=1; i<obj.length; i++) {
        let fila = document.createElement("tr");
        for(let j=0; j<obj[i].length; j++) {
            let celda = document.createElement("td");
            celda.textContent = obj[i][j];
            fila.appendChild(celda);
        }
        tablaBody.appendChild(fila);
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<span class="input-group-text"><i class="bi bi-envelope"></i></span>
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="telf" id="telf">
```

Comment: ¿Dónde se está insertando la fecha? No se está trabajando con fechas en ningún momento

Comment: Ahi lo edite... esa fecha puedo insertarla pero al leerla me manda el error que puse mas arriba..

Comment: No estas teniendo en cuenta el campo de fecha para leerlo de la forma que sea oportuna para añadirlo a la tabla. Actualmente simplemente lo añades como texto desde `celda.textContent = obj[i][j];`

Comment: Agrega un [mcve] (deberías incluir cómo llamas la función que lee los datos así como un ejemplo de la estructura de `obj`.

Comment: @DavidFernándezFlores y como debería de leerlo entonces?

Answer (score 0):

estoy aprendiendo GAS, y me paso algo similar con las fechas a la hora de mostrarlas.
En mi caso, al recuperar los datos desde la sheet debía convertir las fechas con el método "toLocaleDateString()" para que se puedan visualizar correctamente.
ejemplo:
CODIGO.GS

```
function getContacto(){
   let datosContactos= hojaContactos.getDataRange().getValues();
   datosContactos.shift();  //elimino la fila de encabezados
   let data =[];
   datosContactos.map(contacto => { 
    contacto[3] = contacto[3].toLocaleDateString();      
    data.push(contacto);  
   });      
  return data;  
}
```

(contacto[3] sería la posición de la fecha.)

No se si te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, ahora ando aprendiendo python pero cuando vuelva a Gas de seguro probare ese codigo, ya que nunca me resulto bien el tema de la fecha jajaja